# C# HTML Tag parsing through REGEX

Tags: c#, regex

```
<p style="color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;">My name is Faysal </p>
```

I want to parse only the String "My name is Faysal". I've written the following snippets,but it returns nothing. What should I need to modify?

```
 WebClient web = new WebClient();
        String html = web.DownloadString("http://www.dmp.gov.bd/application/index/pressdetails/press_159");


        MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, "<p style=\"color: rgb(34, 34, 34); font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;\">\\s*(.+?)\\s*</p>", RegexOptions.Singleline);


        foreach (Match m in m1) {
            String head = m.Groups[1].Value;

            Console.WriteLine(head);
        }
```

Comment: [Wouldn't you prefer a nice HTML parser instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/102937)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, I was about to propose HTML Agility Pack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: I know it can be done through HTML Agility Pack. but I want to make this code work anyhow.

Comment: Yeah, I know how you feel. Most people feel that cars are the best highway vehicles, but I wanted to be the first to traverse the Mass Pike with a yacht. (To be honest, I understand that feeling that "I'm 99% there anyway" - but as someone who's tried, trust me - HTML will always throw a formatting curveball at you.)

Answer (score 0):

> You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML.

*retrieved from ["RegEx match open tags"...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)*

I hope you will learn just like I did a long time ago. You can NOT parse HTML using RegEx. It is more efficient to use a parser built for HTML.

- If your page is in XML or XHTML, you can use the built-in parsing libraries.
  For example, `System.Xml.XmlDocument`.
- If it is pure HTML, use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), or another similar parser.

What I would do in your case, is select the first `p` element, that has the style attribute set to the "whatever".

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

## No, please don't look down here!

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

Excuse me mods, if this answer is too long.

.

.

.

.

What you see below is UGLY, and NOT RECOMMENDED! I BEG OF YOU, DON'T LOOK!

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

> ["lea͠ki̧n͘g fr̶ǫm ̡yo​͟ur eye͢s̸ ̛l̕ik͏e liq​uid pain, the song of re̸gular exp​ression parsing will exti​nguish the voices of mor​tal man from the sp​here I can see it can you see ̲͚̖͔̙î̩́t̲͎̩̱͔́̋̀ it is beautiful t​he final snuffing of the lie​s of Man ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T ALL I​S LOST the pon̷y he comes he c̶̮omes he comes the ich​or permeates all MY FACE MY FACE ᵒh god no NO NOO̼O​O NΘ stop the an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨe̠̅s ͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e n​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ   "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

.

If you absolutely have your heart set on using RegEx (kill me for saying this), then try the following expression.

```
<p style=\"color: rgb\(34, 34, 34\); font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;\">\s*(.+?)\s*</p>
```

It's the same, except the parentheses around "rgb" are escaped. And I changed "\s" to "\s"

### **Edit**

If it helps, I viewed the HTML from that website, and I could not find "My name is Faysal".